# Flutter saving Map<String, Object> to Shared Preferences

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences, shopping-cart

This is my Code to store CartItems.

I want to store it in Shared Preferences as cartItems since on refresh, the data are being lost.
Also I want to have function in the CartItem to check if the Product is in the cart or not so that I can make it checked/unchecked.

```
class CartItem {
  final String id;
  final String prodID;
  final String title;
  final String img;
  final double quantity;
  final double price;
  final double availQuantity;

  CartItem({
    @required this.id,
    @required this.prodID,
    @required this.title,
    @required this.quantity,
    @required this.price,
    @required this.img,
    this.availQuantity,
  });

}

class Cart with ChangeNotifier {
  Map<String, CartItem> _items = {};
  Map<String, CartItem> get items {
    return {..._items};
  }

  int get itemCount {
    return _items.length;
  }
  void addItem(String productId, double price, String title, String img,
      double availQuantity) {
    if (_items.containsKey(productId)) {
      _items.update(
        productId,
        (existingCartItem) => CartItem(
          id: existingCartItem.id,
          title: existingCartItem.title,
          img: existingCartItem.img,
          price: existingCartItem.price,
          quantity: existingCartItem.quantity + 1,
          availQuantity: existingCartItem.availQuantity,
        ),
      );
    } else {
      _items.putIfAbsent(
        productId,
        () => CartItem(
          id: productId,
          title: title,
          img: img,
          price: price,
          quantity: 1,
          availQuantity: availQuantity,
        ),
      );
    }

    notifyListeners();
  }

}
```

I tried many ways to convert to string and call setString(),
convert to List too. but couldn't accomplish.
Help needed.

Comment: Cart should persist on the server right

Comment: I recommend you to use sqflite for flutter

Comment: I dont want it to save to server.

Answer (score 1):

You can store it if you convert the Map to a String as follows:

```
import 'dart:convert';
...
String mapToStr = json.encode(map);
```

When you want to get the string out of shared preferences and use it as a Map again, decode it from String to Map again as follows:

```
Map<String, Object> strToMap = json.decode(mapToStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

it's possible to see your function that save in sharedPreference,
Do you have try to convert tour `Cart` in `Map<String, dynamic>` and save. I think you try to save your directly your Cart class, but it's not allowed, you can only save `int`, `string`, `List`, `Map` ...

Comment: how do I convert it to Map<String,dynamic> and save it.

Comment: you can create a function or a getter for this

Comment: `Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      "id": this.id
      "prodID": this.prodID
      "title": this.title
      "img": this.img
      "quantity": this.quantity
      "price": this.price
      "availQuantity": this.availQuantity
    }
  }`

Answer (score 0):

You can check from this code, if the product is in cart or not:

```
bool checkProductAddedToCart(productId) {
   if (_items.containsKey(productId)) {
      return true;
   } else {
      return false;
   }
}
```